# Is H antigen considered as an agglutinogen?

Tags: biochemistry, physiology, hematology, blood-group

A and B antigens which have the potential to cause agglutination in certain cases are called agglutinogens. But, as far as I know, H antigen cannot give rise to agglutination. So can it be said that H antigen also is an agglutinogen?

Answer (score 2):

`H` antigen is a precursor for `A` and `B` antigens, and `hh` (recessive) individuals do not express this antigen. See [Bombay blood group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hh_blood_group). This is an example of epistasis. Since `H` antigen is present in all `A`,`B`,`AB` and `O` blood groups, transfusion from any of these to an `hh` individual will cause a haemolytic reaction. Anti-H antibodies are agglutinins and have been referred to as agglutinins in the scientific literature.

> The fairly strong anti-H agglutinins present in **'Bombay'** and
>   **'para-Bombay'** individuals (see *5.5.6*) are generally accompanied by anti-A and anti-B, neither of which can be separated from the
>   anti-H specific antibodies.
>
> ---
>
> <sup>Schenkel-Brunner, Helmut. *[Human blood groups: chemical and
>   biochemical basis of antigen specificity.](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-7091-6294-1)* Springer Science &
>   Business Media, 2000. e-Book ISBN: 978-3-7091-6294-1</sup>